# How can I get the full reason phrase (or the raw response) with jax-rs?

Tags: java, http, jax-rs, httpresponse

I have an API that is returning a response with the following status line, in certain conditions:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error: An error occurred (23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'name'
```

I am catching the resulting `WebApplicationException` and then using the following to try and get the reason phrase:

```
e.getResponse().getStatusInfo().getReasonPhrase()
```

However, this only returns "Internal Server Error" which is not very helpful. I would like to log the full reason phrase so I can log something more specific, when something goes wrong.

Is there any way to get the full phrase? If not, is there a way to get the raw response from the exception's response object? Then I can at least try and parse it myself.

**Edit:** Also, I can confirm that the body is empty and no suitable information appears in any other header. I'm checking the raw response with [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com).

**Edit 2:** I am using cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs 2.7.5

Comment: What implementation of JAX-RS (with exact version) you're using?

Comment: @Jk1 I am using cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs 2.7.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the `getReasonPhrase` call only returns the phrase as defined by the HTTP response code spec -- it's not actually parsing it out of the status line. It's odd that the application you're calling writes the diagnostic message to the status line and not the response body. Perhaps it's a bug in that application?

**EDIT** As I thought, the reason phrase is [hard-coded in the status enum](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.java#Response.StatusType) (not even localizable! Bad Sun!)

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. However, since it is valid to provide custom reason phrases, I would have thought there would be some way to access them?

The application does not write out anything to the body on 500 errors, only on 400 errors. Is this actually against the standard/best practice? If so, I might be able to convince the authors of the application to change it.

Comment: From the spec: "The Status-Code element is a 3-digit integer result code of the attempt to understand and satisfy the request. These codes are fully defined in section 10. The Reason-Phrase is intended to give a short textual description of the Status-Code. The Status-Code is intended for use by automata and the Reason-Phrase is intended for the human user. The client is not required to examine or display the Reason- Phrase."

Comment: Yup this looks right to me. I think you are right and the correct answer is that the message should be returned in the body. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Well from the same spec (a few lines below @TomG 's quote):  The reason phrases listed here are only recommendations -- they MAY be replaced by local equivalents without affecting the protocol.